# How to push onto a multidimensional associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through some HTML form elements on a page like so.

```
var itemsArray = new Array();
$('input[type="text"].qty').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).val()) {
        itemsArray[index]['qty'] = $(this).val();
        itemsArray[index]['itemPrice'] = $(this).parents('.control-group').find('.itemPrice').val();
        itemsArray[index]['itemID'] = $(this).parents('.control-group').find('.itemID').val();
    }
});
```

The `index` i'm hoping to be 0,1,2,3 etc.. like a regular array.  With the sub elements being associative and assigned to various values.

I'm getting this error in the console.

`TypeError: itemsArray[index] is undefined`

Comment: in Javascript, there are no associative arrays. there are Arrays, and Objects. Arrays can contain Objects, and Objects can contain Arrays. In your case, you want an array of objects, so for each index, you will have to add an object to the array, then populate the object. YOu could also create the object then add it to the array, which ever makes more sense.

Comment: Your code can be condensed to this: http://pastebin.com/H0AP8Y20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using an array of objects. Arrays in Javascript are not really intended to be used in the way you are (the multidimensional part). Also `itemsArray = []` is preferred over `new Array()`.

```
var itemsArray = [];
$('input[type="text"].qty').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).val()) {
        itemsArray.push({
            qty : $(this).val(),
            itemPrice :  $(this).parents('.control-group').find('.itemPrice').val(),
            itemID : $(this).parents('.control-group').find('.itemID').val()
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure each item in the outer array is initialized before you start using it.  Note, I changed to object notation below just for clarity.

```
$('input[type="text"].qty').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).val()) {
        itemsArray[index] = {};
        itemsArray[index].qty = $(this).val();
        itemsArray[index].itemPrice = $(this).parents('.control-group').find('.itemPrice').val();
        itemsArray[index].itemID = $(this).parents('.control-group').find('.itemID').val();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the main reason why people struggle with JavaScript arrays when they're done working on PHP arrays.

Comment: @Ghillied - yes definitely

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says. `itemsArray[index]` is `undefined`, and you cannot assign properties on this. Notice that you don't have a "multidimensional array", but just an array *of* objects. For each new `index`, you will need to create a new object.

```
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.val()) {
    var $parent = $(this).parents('.control-group'); // .closest() should suffice
    itemsArray[index] = {
        qty: $this.val(),
        itemPrice: $parent.find('.itemPrice').val(),
        itemID: $parent.find('.itemID').val()
    };
}
```